# CodeIgniter captcha not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

Hi CodeIgniter captcha is not working in my page.My php gd library enabled but no change result

Comment: This is like calling IT support and saying "My Computer is not working".. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Try include some code so we can get an idea of what may be happening as well as a few more details as Shoban said.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do to debug a CodeIgniter application is turn on log into a DEBUG level. Do this by editing file `system/application/config/config.php`, find these line:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

If the value is `0`, change it to `2`.

After that, make sure the diractory `system/logs` is writable by web server process. Access the application page, then open the log file. In your code, add this line to write it's own log:

```
log_message(LEVEL, MESSAGE);
```

`LEVEL` will be a `DEBUG` or `ERROR`, or else. Read the user_guide for more complete explanation.

CI captcha plugins need you to have correct path to font and cache directory. Follow the example in `system/plugins/captcha_pi.php` file, you should have it worked.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to set your directory permission to 777.

Answer (score 0):

please ensure permission of the folder which store your captcha images.

1. configure your img path in `create_captcha(array('img_path' => $path...))`
2. check img_path permission, and `chmod a+w` if you could